# Next js 13.4 socket.io upgrade

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, websocket, socket.io

I got error upgrading socket.io to next.js 13.4

This was my old server.js code

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

export default function SocketHandler(req, res) {
  if (res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("Already set up");
    res.end();
    return;
  }

  const io = new Server(res.socket.server);
  res.socket.server.io = io;

  io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("send-message", (obj) => {
      io.emit("receive-message", obj);
    });
  });

  console.log("Setting up socket");
  res.end();
}
```

and this was my client.js code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

let socket;

const Home = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [allMessages, setAllMessages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socketInitializer();

    return () => {
      socket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  async function socketInitializer() {
    await fetch("/api/socket");

    socket = io();

    socket.on("receive-message", (data) => {
      setAllMessages((pre) => [...pre, data]);
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("emitted");

    socket.emit("send-message", {
      username,
      message
    });
    setMessage("");
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Chat app</h1>
      <h1>Enter a username</h1>

      <input value={username} onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)} />

      <br />
      <br />

      <div>
        {allMessages.map(({ username, message }, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {username}: {message}
          </div>
        ))}

        <br />

        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            name="message"
            placeholder="enter your message"
            value={message}
            onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            autoComplete={"off"}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

now that I am trying to learn typescript and next js app router in 13.4.

I could only convert my client.js to client.tsx but there's an error while converting server.js to server/route.ts. I can't use functions like in old next js. I have to use

```
export default function POST {}
```

this types of function. I need a help to convert it into typescript + making it work with new latest next js.

**Sorry for my bad English**

Answer (score 0):

Update your nextjs version to `13.5.x` and it shall work, as a issue that was previously making this code not work, is fixed now, in `13.5.x`

Answer (score -2):

### Next 13.4 API Routes

Your API route should look something like this when converted to typescript:

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function POST(req: Request) {
    const { data } = await req.json();

    /*
        Do something here
    */

    return NextResponse.json({message: "Hello World"})
}
```

You would use the same format for any other handlers. Hope this helps.

Comment: Looking at his snippets I don't think his project is using the approuter.